# How to include methods of models in RSpec test cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm writing some Rspec tests with capybara , and as part of that I need some methods of model.

I have created my model as:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_name
    #some stuff..
  end
end
```

Now, I want to use `MyModel` in my Rspec test cases.

I tried to include`config.include Models` in `spec_helper.rb` but it throws error

```
Uninitialized constant Models
```

And when I tried to include

```
include MyModel.new.method_name()
```

it throws error `` `include': wrong argument type nil (expected Module) (TypeError) ``

Without including any model class it runs test cases, but then my test cases are useless.

Here is my Rspec test case

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "State Agency Page" do
    let(:state_data) { FactoryGirl.build(:state_data) } 
    require 'mymodel.rb'
    before {visit state_modifier_path}

    it "should have breadcrumb", :js=>true do
        page.should have_css('.breadcrumb')
    end
end
```

Please provide any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we get a little more info. The scenario sounds odd, i.e. capybara is used to test across the whole stack - like simulating what the user would do at the web browser. Maybe post the whole test if possible?

Comment: perhaps if you add your entire test file this will make sense - show us the rspec file you're trying to run

Comment: I don't understand. If you have a model instance, call the method on the model. If you have a general-purpose method inside a model, put it somewhere else like a utility class or a module. Your models are already available in your specs, you don't need to require anything. So far the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "your test cases are useless", but you seem to misunderstand the role of Ruby's `include` method.

With Rails, or the use of the `rspec-rails` gem with RSpec, your classes will be autoloaded when you reference the corresponding class constant (e.g. `MyModel`). So there generally is no need to do manual "loading" of individual models. Just make sure you have `require 'spec_helper'` at the beginning of your specs.

As for the errors you were getting with your attempts to use `include`, I suggest you find and read a Ruby reference to understand the semantics of the `include` method and why each attempt of yours failed in the way it did.

Comment: Thanks.. I got it now.